# Try catch block in nested foreach loop not returning correct output, c#

Tags: c#, debugging, foreach, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I know this question has been asked many times, but I cannot get the logic behind it. I have this nested foreach loop structured like this:

```
 foreach (string currentFile in csvfiles)//loops through all csv files
 {
     string fileName = currentFile.Substring(Input_Path.Length);//works
     try
     {
         foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(currentFile))
         {
             wafer = Wafer_value(line, wafer);
         }
         Console.WriteLine(wafer);
         Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName));
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e);
         Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(Error_Path, fileName));
         continue;
     }
 }
```

and the method for it:

```
public static string Wafer_value(string line, string wafer)
{
    try
    {
        if (line.Contains("Wafer"))
        {
            wafer = line;
        }
        string[] separatingStrings = { "Wafer: ", "," };
        string[] str = wafer.Split(separatingStrings, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return str.First();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw new Exception();
    }
}//End Function Wafer_value
```

What the code is supposed to that is if there is an exception in the method, it will throw to the main method, where it will move that file to an error folder. When there is no exception in the method, it will proceed as normal, then move it to the archiveDirectory, which is the main folder. So this is where I am stuck. When there are all files with exceptions, it moves it to the error folder. However, when there is a file with no exception thrown in the mix, it only moves one of the exception files to the error folder, then moves all the files remaining, even if they have exceptions to the main folder.

For this, the the inner foreachloop loops through all the lines of the file, and the outer foreachloop loops through all the csvfiles.

What would I do to make sure that all the files that throw exceptions go to the error folder?

Comment: You are overwriting the `wafer = Wafer_value(line, wafer);` over and over

Comment: Oh so I would I need to have like another try catch block in the inner foreach loop to try and break out of it?

Comment: Try/catch blocks which throws an other exception, aren't useful. Only catch an exception when you "solve" it.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Not quite, there are many cases where rethrowing can be used: to add more context to the exception, log it...

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? It is usually the best way to discover this kind of problems

Comment: For this, I know it may seem like bad practice, but I am just trying to catch any exception, then move it to the error folder

Comment: @vc74 sure, but at least use the original exception as inner exception.

Comment: Why is the whole method `Wafer_value` one big try..catch? Exceptions should be exceptional. What could go wrong? `line` _could_ be null (doubtful, if the source is `File.ReadAllLines`). So check that and throw a qualified `ArgumentNullException` (instead of a hard(er) to track `NullReferenceException`). Same for `wafer` if the `line` doesn't contain `"Wafer"`. The splitting itself shouldn't throw, but with "RemoveEmptyEntries" You _could_ end up with an empty array, so `.First()` might throw. But if that's an "expected" possibility, you could at least check `.Any()` first and then throw.

Comment: Point is, I'd get rid of the try..catch in `Wafer_value`. It doesn't do anything but log and re-throw the "exception", but the outside code then redundantly logs it again. So why not just let the outside code log it _once_.

Comment: So just Have like a try catch in the loops instead?

Comment: First, I'd separate the logic. Have a `DoStuffWithONEFile(string currentfile){ [...] }`, then your outside loop becomes `foreach (string currentFile in csvfiles) { DoStuffWithONEFile(currentFile); }` and suddendly, you don't have to think about that outer loop anymore. Then, inside the new method, put everything that's currently inside that outer loop; try..catch and all. So that basically becomes `try [something with the file]; [Move file to "good" folder if it worked] catch [log exception]; [Move file to "bad" folder]`.

Comment: Then the `[something with the file]` should (as far as I see) not need another try..catch. It should just care about: _if_ there is something that I _know_ can go wrong, check it and throw as qualified an exception as possible; and if something goes wrong I _don't_ know about or can't do anything about, let it bubble up, so the try..catch in `DoStuffWithONEFile` (or whoever is calling me) can take care about it.

Comment: _Iff_ you think, the `[something with the file]` part could be used to gather more interesting information (as @vc74 pointed out), like the exact line number that caused the error, _then_ you could further encapsulate stuff in try..catch. For example `int currentLineNumber = whatever; try { [something that could fail unexpectedly] } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception($"Error in line {currentLineNumber} of file {currentFile}.", ex); }`.